# how to define order of values from max to min in importance score of features using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, random-forest

I calculate score of impotance for my dataset with 30 features and i column of supposed class. And did plot. But values in array ordered not by value of score of impotance of features. Witch variable of class in numpy or matplotlib manages by it?

```
from pandas import read_csv, read_excel

from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

# load data


names = ['8,oct18', '3,oct18', '4,oct18', '3,sen17', '3,sen17', '4,sen17', '8,sen17', '3,aug17', 
         '8,aug17','4,aug17', '3,apr17', '4,apr17', '8,apr17', '3,jan17', '8,jan17', '4,jan17', 'jan19', 'jan19',
        'jan19', 'may18', 'may18', 'may18', '11, sen17', '11, dec2017', '12,dec2017', '11,aug 2017', 
         '12,aug 2017', '11, apr 2017', '12, apr 2017', '30t', 'class']

dataframe = read_excel("/home/qw/myprojects/valuevo/data.xlsx", names = names)

array = dataframe.values

X = array[:,0:30]

Y = array[:,30]

# feature extraction

model = ExtraTreesClassifier()

model.fit(X, Y)

print(names, '=', model.feature_importances_)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#case x,y were 31x30 before this:
names = ['8,oct18', '3,oct18', '4,oct18', '3,sen17', '3,sen17', '4,sen17', '8,sen17', '3,aug17', 
         '8,aug17','4,aug17', '3,apr17', '4,apr17', '8,apr17', '3,jan17', '8,jan17', '4,jan17', 'jan19', 'jan19',
        'jan19', 'may18', 'may18', 'may18', '11, sen17', '11, dec2017', '12,dec2017', '11,aug 2017', 
         '12,aug 2017', '11, apr 2017', '12, apr 2017', '30t']
x = np.array(names)
y = np.array(model.feature_importances_)
plt.title("RF score") 

plt.plot(y,x)
```

next python throws plot. How to order scores by values?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the sort order of your values with `np.argsort` and use that index to sort your x and y values together:

```
sort_ix = np.argsort(model.feature_importances_)
x = np.array(names)[sort_ix]
y = np.array(model.feature_importances_)[sort_ix]
plt.plot(y, x)
```

I'm not sure why you are calling your x value `y` and your y value `x` though. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, it is strange thing. It is just error)). Thank you for a suggest !